# electron - electron repulsion and shielding effect

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

What is difference between shielding and electron electron repulsion. When I read this article , I came to know that both are different. First Read this paragraph and see the graph of ionization energy.
[image]
[image]

Here we can see that author is writting that when we neglect electron electron repulsion we see that effective nuclear charge is increasing and ionization energy should increase but when we include this factor we find a drop in predicted ionization energy.
Now my questions is when we are talking about effective nuclear charge , haven't we already included the shielding factor which itself means repulsion  that valence shell electron feels due to all other electrons in atom. So how author can say that he neglected the electron - electron repulsion while predicting ionization energy? Is not shielding same to repulsion?

reference - B.J. Duke (1978) Educ. Chem., vol. 15, p. 186.

Answer (score 2):

> Everyone who is going to answer in one or two line , don't waste your time because I am not as Intelligent and Smart as you

I think you are smart enough to do this research and the answer should be in two lines.

> Now my questions is when we are talking about effective nuclear charge , haven't we already included the shielding factor which itself means repulsion that valence shell electron feels due to all other electrons in atom. So how author can say that he neglected the electron - electron repulsion while predicting ionization energy? Is not shielding same to repulsion?

$z_{eff}$ includes only the repulsion of the core electrons, it is the potential experienced by the valence electrons, the e-e repulsion of the valence electrons is not included in the [effective charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge).

Comment: Just read the example section any of these  articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules  or https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/Chem_1201/Unit_2._Periodic_Properties_of_the_Elements/2.06%3A_Slater's_Rules  and tell me you are right or wrong.

Comment: You should ask yourself: Why do we need an effective nuclear charge including all the electrons of an atom if an atom is neutral ?

Comment: Have you ever  calculated effective nuclear charge mathematically using slater's rule

Comment: @M06-2x In context of Slater's coefficients and Z_eff, influence of valence electrons is involved by coefficient 0.35(0.30 for 1s
), in contrary to the core electrons with the coeffiecient 1.00(0.85). While the mutual valence electron influence cannot be easily identified as being subtracted from nucleus charge via interaction of spherically symmetric charges(densities), they still contribute to the repulsion and Z_eff decrease, what is reflected by the 0.30 coefficient (which does not distinguish repulsions between and within orbitals).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR; version:**

Nucleus shielding is electron–electron repulsion that fits the two conditions:

- Shielding electrons as the group have spherically symmetric probability density around the nucleus.
- Their probability density do not (significantly) overlap with the density of shielded electrons.

Electron–electron repulsion that does not fit those conditions is not called shielding. The boundary is not sharp, as seen for n-1 level electrons shielding ns, np electrons.

In context of Slater's rules, repulsion by other electron in the same (Slater's) orbital group is expressed as the shielding equivalent, like if the electron were shielded by an extra 0.35 electron in core orbitals instead.

---

Every nucleus shielding is electron-electron repulsion, but not every electron-electron repulsion is nucleus shielding. The shielding covers mostly radial repulsion component of inner electrons, effectively subtracting from nucleus charge due spherical charge density geometry.

Core electrons can be formally added to the nucleus to approximate the total electrostatic force of a single effective nucleus change.  Electrons of the same orbital groups have this component diminished ( 0.30 versus 0.85 for n-1 vs 1.0 for n-2 in [Slater coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules)), as their radial repulsion is part-time neutral, part-time even reversed.

E-E repulsion within the same orbital or orbital group covers mostly the tangential repulsion part, increasing the electron potential energy as well.

---

Shielding and electron-electron repulsion are not different interactions, but the different **interaction geometry**. They are distinguished because of two different ways how they are evaluated and processed.

Objects with spherically symmetric distribution of their mass respectively charge, affected by a distant quadratic force(*), behave if they had been point objects. This goes  back to Newton, reportedly one of reasons for him to invent integral calculus.

It applies to a spherically symmetric probability density as well, assuming there is no or negligible overlapping. Fully filled p, d or f orbital sets have this spherical symmetry. s orbitals are spherically symmetric natively.

Core, filled orbital sets with spherically symmetric density can be viewed formally as if the nucleus had been surrounded by a big, spherically symmetric negatively charged object of the charge and size of the orbital set. It can be than evaluated as their charge being subtracted from the true nucleus charge.
This is addressed by the shielding coefficient 1.00 in [Slater coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules), the electron charge being fully subtracted (0.85 for partial overlapping).

OTOH, electrons in valence orbital mutually repulse each other in such a way that cannot be accounted as shielding in the above sense. They mutually repulse themselves from all angles. This increases electron potential energy and is addressed by the effective shielding coefficient 0.35 resp. 0.30 AS IF such a charge had been added to the shielding core.

Note that the Slater's rules/coefficients do not distinguish cases of valence electrons being in different or same orbital.

---

(*) gravitational and electrostatic forces with $F \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$

Comment: please provide some references that shielding is radial repulsion and E-E repulsion is tangential.

Comment: Well, such references should be in the first place the part of your homework within the question formulation. Shielding is explained in textbook chapters of classical electrostatics. And repulsion which is not shielding as is not radial....

Comment: Can a post a photo of such explanation because I couldn't find it

Comment: Review search results of queries like [site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org  nucleus shielding electrons](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+OR+site%3Alibretexts.org++nucleus+shielding+electrons)

Comment: Friend, you must have read this explanation somewhere,  just tell me where you read that  ?  Please don't play with me . I am mentally exhausted.

Comment: please  answer @Poutnik

Comment: I will not answer until I see the documented explicit effort of searching, reviewing and analyzing available info. Do not expect others to answer if you do not show significant attempts (not shown indistinguishable from not existent) to find the answer before asking, or at least after asking. It would be otherwise like spoon-feeding. See 3 of 5 closing votes. // Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to prevent misunderstanding,  need of clarification, objections, downvoting or closure.