# Refrence on shielding effect vs inter electronic repulsion

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrons

Recently I came across a very interesting concept , some scholars were saying that -

***Shielding accounts just one component (radial) of interelectronic repulsion not complete repulsion***

Who they are -

[Shielding vs electron-electron repulsion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/164460/129242)

https://lavelle.chem.ucla.edu/forum/viewtopic.php?t=49293#p177071

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/175176/129242

When I searched for this concept on internet, in books and articles I couldn't find there exists such a concept. Just as I was on the verge of giving up all hope and sinking into despair, I stumbled upon something that rekindled my hope - **Answer  to problem 7.98 in the book "Chemistry the central science by Theodore L. Brown"**

[image: Chemistry the central science]

Although this book doesn't say anything about shielding and interelectronic repulsion is same or not except this answer which says that shielding and interelectronic repulsion are same for S orbital which concludes that  those may be different for P or D orbital.

That's all I found. ***Is there someone who could discuss about this concept in detail?***

**Or**

***could you just help me to find out some books or articles where can I find this type of language (radial and tangential component of repulsion, shielding is a component of repulsion etc) ?***

Comment: You should rather add it to the original question as elaboration, not to fragment effort of yourself and others.  I am going to write/entend the answer somewhat later, not by a phone.

Comment: to which question  should  i add it ? i will definitely add

Comment: There is just one your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The answers in the second link are clear enough, the shielding and the electronic repulsion are two different concepts, a quantitative analysis may be necessary the understand that they have a different energy impact.

The ion $\ce{He+}$ has an analytical ground state with one electron in the $1s$ orbital creating a shield for another incoming electron before the singlet state is formed, *there is no repulsion but there is screening*. The shielding and repulsion effects are related, but are different processes described as follows:

In the case of $\ce{He+}$, the ground state energy is $\epsilon_{1s}=-\frac{Z^2}{2n^2}$ ($Z=2$, $n=1$) a.u = $-54.42$ eV is also the orbital energy. To describe the repulsion, $\ce{He}$ is the simplest example, but the ground state has no analytical expression. The repulsion between the electrons at the  positions $r_1$, $r_2$, assuming that that the state remains a hydrogenic solution $\psi^2_{1s}(r)=e^{- Zr}$ is given by a perturbation $\Delta V_{ee} = \int\psi^2_{1s}(r_1)\frac{1}{|\bf{r}_1-\bf{r}_2|}\psi^2_{1s}(r_2)r_1^2r_2^2d\Omega_1d\Omega_2$, the value of this integral is $\Delta V_{ee} = \frac{5}{8}Z$ a. u. $= 34.01$ eV, the ground state energy $\epsilon_{1s}=-\frac{Z^2}{2n^2}+\Delta V_{ee} = -74.83$ eV, the accuracy is poor, there is a [variationnal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_atom) leading to a better accuracy. The correct value of the orbital energy is given by the first ionization energy $-I = 24.59 $ eV. Obviously there is no shielding in this singlet state, the shielding starts with the lithium atom. There is no exact approximation : $\ce{Li+}$ is similar to the Helium atom, $\Delta V_{ee}(\ce{Li+}) = \frac{5}{8}(Z=3) = 51.20 $ eV, the repulsion is higher because the $1s$ orbital is more localized due to an additional nucleus charge.

The third elcction of $\ce{Li}$ has a $2s$ state orthogonal to $1s$, if the inner electrons $1s^2$ reduce the charge to an effective charge of $Z_{eff}=1$ on the third electron, the $2s$ level will have $\epsilon_{2s}^{approx}\frac{(Z=1)^2}{2\times 2^2} = -3.40$ eV higher in energy compared to the experimental value :  $\epsilon_{2s}=-I = - 5.39$ eV, if we use $\epsilon_{2s}=\frac{Z_{eff}}{2n^2}$, $Z_{eff} = 1.26$, smaller than the charge of the nucleus ($Z=3$).  The shielding of the nucleus $1s$ is $s = |Z_eff - 1(3-2) |= 0.26$, in agreement with the [Slater's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules) as an answer to [the third link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/175166/electron-electron-repulsion-and-shielding-effect/175176).

The shielding and the electronic repulsion are different and have different contributions, the repulsion has a significant contribution of about $51$ eV, but the shielding related to the nuclear charge has a correction $\frac{Z-Z^{eff}}{2n^2}$ of about $6$ eV, but they are correlated. The angular dependence of the orbitals for $\ell > 0$ gives spatial vacancies where the electronic density is very week, the shielding is less efficient compared to the example above and again not directly related to the electronic repulsion.

Comment: How can you say that -"there is no repulsion but there is screening". Repulsion without screening makes sense when we talk about same subshell or orbital but how does screening without repulsion makes sense, when screening is also a 
part or component of repulsion. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/175176/135928